# Как получить DataFrame в одну строку, из нескольких столбцов исходного DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Есть исходный DataFrame из двух столбцов:

```
tf = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(1,13)), 'B': list(range(10,130,10))})

    A   B
0   1   10
1   2   20
2   3   30
3   4   40
4   5   50
5   6   60
6   7   70
7   8   80
8   9   90
9   10  100
10  11  110
11  12  120
```

Из него нужно получить DataFrame с одной строкой, так:

```
A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4 A_5 A_6 A_7 A_8 A_9 A_10 A_11 A_12 B_1  B_2 B_3 B_4 B_5 B_6 B_7 B_8 B_9 B_10 B_11 B_12
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9   10   11  12   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100   110   120
```

Answer (score 3):

решение в стиле Pandas:

```
t = tf.stack().reset_index(name="val")
res = (t
       .assign(name=t["level_1"] + "_" + t["val"].astype(str))
       .sort_values(["level_1","val"])
       [["name", "val"]]
       .set_index("name")
       .T)
```

результат:

```
In [38]: res
Out[38]: 
name  A_1  A_2  A_3  A_4  A_5  A_6  A_7  A_8  A_9  A_10  A_11  A_12  B_10  B_20  B_30  B_40  B_50  B_60  B_70  B_80  B_90  B_100  B_110  B_120
val     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90    100    110    120
```

Comment: Отличный вариант. 
Только два момента: 
есть опечатка в ссылках на столбцы, указан фрэйм t вместо tf
и по условиям задачи в названии столбцов должен быть индекс строки, а не значение показателя.

Comment: это легко исправить в строке `.assign(name=t["level_1"] + "_" + (t["level_0"]+1).astype(str))` 

тем не менее не заработал такой вариант(KeyError: 'level_1'). только если вынести отдельно формирование индекса так: `t = tf.stack().reset_index(name="val")` , а потом всё работает, спасибо.

Comment: @mr.polden2010, исправил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека и исходная таблица

```
import pandas as pd
tf = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(1,13)), 'B': list(range(10,130,10))})
```

Создаём два пустых списка

```
tr = [] # для списка значений
tr_out_cols = [] # для названий столбцов новой таблицы
```

Запускаем цикл по столбцам исходной таблицы

```
for c in tf.columns:
    tr_out_cols = tr_out_cols + list(c+'_'+str(m) for m in range(1,tf.shape[0]+1))
    tr = tr + tf[c].to_list()
```

Создаём новый DataFrame в ltf

```
ltf = pd.DataFrame( [tr], columns= tr_out_cols )
```